# determinant of TS, where T is rotation and S is reflection operator

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let T and S be linear transformations from $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2.$Let T rotate each vector counter clockwise through an angle $\theta$ about origin and let S be the reflection about the line $y=x$.

Then what is the determinant of TS ?

If $(a_1,a_2)\neq 0\in \mathbb R^2$, let $\alpha$ be the angle that $(a_1,a_2)$ makes with positive x-axis,then $a_1=r cos \alpha ,a_2=rsin \alpha $.
So $T_{\theta}(a_1,a_2)=(rcos (\alpha+\theta),rsin(\alpha+\theta))$, here $\alpha=0$

But I am unable to find the matrices of T and S .Does there exist any simplest way to calculate determinant,please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to write down the matrices; just use the geometric meaning of the determinant. Rotations don't change volumes (nor do they reverse orientation), so $\det T=1$. A reflection has eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$, so its determinant is $-1$. Hence $\det(TS)=\det T\det S=(1)(-1)=-1$.

Nevertheless, it would not be hard to write down the matrices for $S$ and $T$. Remember that the columns of the matrix representation of a linear transformation, with respect to a certain basis, are just the images of the basis elements.